# nsight eclipse for mac lion debug error

Tags: eclipse, cuda, nsight, cuda-gdb

I am using nsight eclipse edition for mac to debug my cuda code. I was able to run cuda-gdb all fine from a terminal but was not able to use the debug function in Nsight. Whenever I started to debug, an error window pops up saying "Error in final launch sequence
Connection is shut down".  My OS is Mac Lion (10.7.4).

I understand the big thing in Cuda 5.0 is the interactive debugging with eclipse but sadly I won't be able to use it unless I switch to Windows or Linux. If anybody has seen this or knows a workaround for this, please let me know and your help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you've hit a known issue in CUDA 5.0 Toolkit. Due to some last-minute change, cuda-gdb (which is a shell script) is not entirely valid in Mac OS X. To remedy the problem:

1. Edit cuda-gdb shell script.
2. Make line `#!/bin/sh` the first line in this script.
3. Save the changes

We apologize for inconvenience. This (and many other) issues will be fixed in the upcoming CUDA 5.0 RC release.

Comment: Thank you Eugene! This solves my problem and it is working really well now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in linux recently.

Error in final launch sequence Connection is shut down which means nsight can not start debugger correctly.

first you have to make sure you can run cuda-gdb in terminal. just type cuda-gdb in terminal, if it says like cuda-gdb cannot find some lib in /usr/lib, just download or relink it. after you done this , rerun   cuda-gdb in terminal, it should work fine. then you can use nsight debugging tool.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. I was able to run cuda-gdb in terminal. As Eugene has pointed out, it is the overhead of cuda-gdb shell script that is causing the problem with nsight. But it is always good to check the terminal version first.